# Are there any benchmark tests that compare ColdFusion to Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coldfusion, benchmarking, railo

This is not a "which language is faster question."

Are there any benchmark tests that compare ColdFusion to Ruby? I've found a lot on Ruby, but there's very little on ColdFusion. It's interesting and informative to look at benchmarks on http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/, but I'm unable to find ColdFusion on their site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColdFusion is an application server, Ruby is a language. It would be easier to compare it to Rails (deployed on Passenger/Nginx for example), in that case you can use for example JMeter and test your exact user scenario.

Comment: Coldfusion isn't an application server, it's generally used to refer to the markup language, CFML, or the platform in general. JRun is the application server most commonly used, but the next version will use Tomcat.

Comment: I think you might have things mixed up a little Zepp.  

Comparing ColdFusion to Rails is like comparing Ruby to Rails.

1) Ruby is a language, which has an interpreter. Rails is a Framework.

2) ColdFusion is a language, which has an interpreter.  ColdFusion also provides built-in app server functionality.  ColdFusion has Frameworks, like CFWheels, ColdMVC, FW/1, ColdBox, and more.

Answer (score -1):

In 2006 I came up with some benchmarks comparing Python 2.4.3 running on an old laptop to ColdFusion 6.1 on a Solaris server. Python was 40-200 times faster than ColdFusion.

Keep in mind this happened 6 years ago and times change. Plus I was using Python instead of Ruby.